# How can I see Android Auto DHU (Desktop Head Unit) logcat?

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to make an Android Auto Screen with the NavigateTemplate, but when I start the app in Android Auto, all the screen is black, but I can't see any error. The black screen is if I use the NavigateTemplate in the app, if I use a normal Template with some text or buttons everything is going okey.

So my question is, is there any option of launching the DHU in debugg mode or any way of looking up a log file, logcat, ...?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in order to see logcat traces from the DHU is to open a wireless connection to the device running Android Auto.

Assuming you want to connect the device to the DHU via usb, the steps I follow are the following:

1. $adb tcpip 5555
2. $adb connect <your_device_ip>:5555

After this step you should be able to see the device listed when doing `adb devices`

3. Android/Sdk/extras/google/auto2.0/desktop-head-unit --usb

Now Android Studio should show you logcat traces coming from Android Auto.